# Reverse an iterator multiple times in Python

Tags: python, iterator

I am trying to reverse the same iterator several times, using the `reversed` function. For instance, with the code:

```
iterator = range(3)
N = 5
k = 0
out = []
while k < N:
    for i in iterator:
        out.append(i)
    iterator = reversed(iterator)
    k += 1
print(out)
```

I would want/expect to have the output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, ... ]
```

But, after the first use of reverse, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'range_iterator' object is not reversible
```

What could be an efficient workaround that does not require unpacking the iterator?

Comment: An iterator by definition cannot be reversed without unpacking. An iterator could be a generator, which just yields the next value at each step, which by definition isn't reversible.

Comment: I agree for a generator, but in this particular case for a range iterator, it would suffice to look at its start, stop, step attributes to build its reversed version without unpacking, wouldn't it?

Comment: And even if it needs to unpack it, I can be ok with that. The problem is, it lets me reverse it once, but then it does not let me reverse the already reversed iterator, which is basically going back to the original range iterator.

Comment: A range object is a special object which supports all sorts special iteration methods. Once you turn it into an actual *iterator*, that's gone. And since you're generically asking about iterators, it was worth pointing out that this isn't generalisable to iterators at all.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#reversed) briefly describes how `reversed` works. While `range_iterator` theoretically could implement a `__reversed__` in the way you describe, it doesn't. My thinking is that the devs are applying "in the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess"; the problem is how to decide how far along the created iterator should be in the iteration, vs. the base iterator.

Comment: It doesn't "let you reverse it" once; it lets you *create* an iterator that iterates in reverse *directly from* the iter*able*.

Comment: You're absolutely right! @deceze, thanks for your input, I'm just frustrated that something apparently so simple is actually not that simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply alternate the original iterator and the reversed iterator.
You can start with this simple example:

```
iterator = range(3)
N = 5
k = 0
out = []
while k < N:
    if k%2 == 0:
        it = iterator
    else:
        it = reversed(iterator)
    for i in it:
        out.append(i)
    k += 1
print(out)

[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: The `if` could be: `it = iterator if k % 2 == 0 else reversed(iterator)` or even: `it = [iterator, reversed(iterator)][k % 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. I knew beforehand that I could just do with a list containing both the original and the reversed version and just select the one I need, but really wanted to see if there was out there something that appears natural to me such as `reversed(reversed(whatever))`. So, making it a bit more compact, and adding a boolean `do_reverse` (which I need in my actual project) I will go with something like this:

```
iterator = range(3)
do_reverse = True
N = 5
k = 0
out = []
while k < N:
    for i in [iterator, reversed(iterator)][k % 2 * do_reverse]:
        out.append(i)
    k += 1
print(out)
```